# SSRS - Is it possible to span a row group header over a column group?

Tags: html, reporting-services, report

- Sample Report showing where header should span

[image]

I hope the attached image explains succinctly what I am asking.  I have a Matrix with a parent row group, a child row group, and a column group.  I need to have a title for each group that spans a column group.  The title will be the value of the Parent Row Group.  Obviously by it's nature, a column group may be one or more columns which makes this very tricky (I hope not impossible though).

Does anyone know if this can be achieved, and if so how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a parent table and put your table in it. The parent table will expand with the child.

Create another table with one column.

Set the dataset to be the same as your current table.

Add grouping and group on **1**.

Make the group text box the same size as your table.

Drop your table in the group text box.

[image]

Add you header.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment or to upvote Hannover Fist's answer, but it is a good way to proceed. You can indeed nest tables. You just need to make sure that the cell of the outer table that you paste the expanding table into does not have any row or column groups around it: you normally get a Detail row group when you simply insert a table, and you'll need to delete that group.

Subreports work too, but it's messy to have to break a long report into many subreports just because you want spanning headers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't 'think' this is possible due to the presence of a column group. The only way I can think of to achieve this would be to create a subreport that displays single parent group (almost identical to what you have now), with a textbox on top of the tablix containing the parent group text.

The main report would then be a single cell table bound to a dataset that just lists the parent groups. In that cell you would place you subreport.